# Is visual studio 2012 ssis shell dragging objects on canvas shaky or impossible?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2012-datatools

In a new version of Visual Studio 2012 (ssis) shell - when dragging objects on the canvas is extremely "shaky" or impossible to move the objects.

They either do not follow the mouse or shake/snap to random points.

I only found two similar threads/issues on Google - with the only suggestion being "have you rebooted" which did not work.

Just curious if anyone else has same issue and found a driver or patch ? that might have caused it (or fixed it !)

The version of VS 2012 Shell is 11.0.50727.1 RTMREL with .NET 4.5.50709
Running on Windows 2008 R2 Server Standard and SQL 2012 Standard

Comment: It's certainly a quirky beast right now. When I drag things about, mine tends to zoom very quickly. My coworker however shows the weird shaky behaviour you're describing. I see her moving the mouse and the task/container is just shimmies about.

Comment: interesting. Well at least it seems like I am not alone, meaning not something I messed up, etc. Maybe we will see a fix soon!

Comment: @bbaley I've been using the VS2010 shell version (SSIS 2012), and still have issues with objects flying away when moving and resizing. I'm not so sure you can count on a fix soon, unfortunately.

Comment: @bbaley,
I'm also still having the same issue and according to Microsoft's team, they're not able to reproduce the problem, so there's no fix in the works. [ref](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/790470/when-dragging-ssis-objects-on-canvas-the-objects-shake-jiggle-jitter)

Comment: Looks like Mike Honey has beat me to the punch but yes, CU7 should address the issue. [KB 2883424](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2883424)

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be two separate issues here:

1. When moving objects, they fly around wildly.  This started in VS 2010 and continues in VS2012.  Ref: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/776664/ssis-2012-control-flow-moving-objects-is-unusable
2. Shaking.  This issue seems to appear with VS2012.

Apparently a recent hotfix resolves these issues (havent tried it myself). Ref: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/805774/ssis-designer-for-visual-studio-2012-is-close-to-unusable